# Is there a way to print out the index of an array member?

Tags: c++, arrays

For example, I have an array that reads:

```
std::string month[] = {January, February, March, April, May, June, July, 
August, September, October, November, December};
```

If I do:

```
std::cout << month[2];
```

it prints out "March", but what if I wanted it to print the chronological value in which it sits inside the array? I.e., "2".

Comment: `std::cout << "month " << index << ": " << month[index];`?

Comment: Well, `month[2];` obviously maps on to  `2`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you mean you have the string "March" and you want to map it to the number 2? Or that you have the number 2 but you want to print it as a string "2"? Or something else?

Comment: Or do you want a function that, given a `string`, finds that in the array and prints its index (if found)??

Comment: _@J.A. Aranda_ Unless you have some macros or `constexpr` variables defined `January, February, March, April, May, June, July, 
August, September, October, November, December` aren't `std::string`s BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can `std::find` the string in the array, and then calculate the `std::distance` of that from the start of the array.

```
std::string month[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

std::size_t getIndex(const std::string & text) {
    auto pos = std::find(std::begin(month), std::end(month), text);
    return std::distance(std::begin(month), pos);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getIndex("March") << " " << getIndex("Not a month");
}
```

With the output

```
2 12
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to print the index of the array element that is at the index 2. You can do that like this:

```
std::cout << 2;
```